# linked list sublist method-java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, sublist

I am attempting to write a subList method, which returns a list consisting of the current object list inclusively between indexes `fromIndex` and `toIndex`.

For example, if I had list consisting of

> 3 5 7 9 11 20 23

and I called `subList(0,3)`, I should get a new list of

> 3 5 7 9

returned.

I am using helper methods to assist in writing the method. My logic in writing this method is that I assign the head node to to be the node at index `fromIndex` while assigning the last node in the list to the node at index `toIndex`, but nothing gets returned. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I am created an add method that that adds nodes to a list. I am still trying to write my own subList method to work.

EDIT2: I have updated some codes, which can be seen at the bottom (disregard older ones above). The fromIndex and toIndex are inclusive in the new sublist.

```
private class Node<N extends Comparable<N>> {
    private N data;
    private Node<N> next;
}

private Node<L> head;

public List() {
    head=null;
}   

public void add(Node<L> node) {
        Node<L> add = new Node<L>();
        add.data = node.data;
        add.next = null;
        getFinal().next = add;
    } 

public Node<L> getFinal(){
    Node<L> node = head;
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
    }
    return node;
}

public int size() {
    if (head == null) return 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (Node<L> curr = head; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
        counter++;
    return counter;
}

public List<L> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
            throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        List<L> n=new List<L>();
        Node<L> tail= new Node<L>();
        n.head=nthItem(fromIndex);
        tail=n.getFinal();
        tail=nthItem(toIndex);
        return n;
    }

public Node<L> nthItem(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size()) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    Node<L> ptr = head;

    int i = 0;
    while (ptr != null) {
        if (i == index) return ptr;
        i++;
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }

    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

---

updated code

```
private void add(Node<L> node) {
        if(head==null){
            head=node;
        } else {
            getFinal().next = node;
        }
    }

public List<L> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
        throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(fromIndex<0 || fromIndex>size()-1 || toIndex<0 || toIndex>size()-1){ //size() is 1 bigger than max index so I subtract 1 from size() to equal them out
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    List<L> n=new List<L>();
    Node<L> startNode = head;
    int counter=0;
    while(startNode!=null){
         if(counter>=fromIndex && counter<=toIndex){ //fromIndex and toIndex are inclusive so I've added the equals to them. However, it enters an infinite loop, which I do not understand why.
              n.add(startNode);
         }
         startNode=startNode.next;
         counter++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 - why are you doing this? LinkedList would be fine and doesn't need rewriting...

Point 2 (or b) - your sublist function creates a new list, sets its head and then sets a temporary variable to contain the desired tail of the sublist...

In a linked list, if you have a node, then that node represents the remainder of that list from that point onwards. To solve your problem, you would need to clone all the nodes to create your sublist, setting the tail of the last clone to null.

But why do it?

--- EDIT - to clarify the answer

```
public List<L> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    Node<L> currentInOriginal = nthItem(fromIndex);

    int count = (toIndex - fromIndex) + 1;

    List<L> newSubList = new List<L>();
    newSubList.head = new Node<L>(current.data);

    Node<L> lastItemInList = newSubList.head;
    int soFar = 1;

    currentInOriginal = currentInOriginal.next;
    while(currentInOriginal!=null && soFar<count) {
        lastItemInList.next = new Node<L>(currentInOriginal.data);
        listItemInList = lastItemInList.next;

        currentInOriginal=currentInOriginal.next;
        soFar++;
    }

    return newSubList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct you have to loop starting from head and return all values if the index in-between fromIndex and toIndex. Before you start you also need to verify that the indexes supplied are valid.

Something on this line

```
public List<L> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
        throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(fromIndex<0 || fromIndex>size() || toIndex<fromIndex || toIndex>size()){
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    List<L> n=new List<L>();
    Node<L> startNode = head;
    int counter=0;
    while(startNode!=null){
         if(counter>fromIndex && counter<toIndex){
              n.add(startNode);
         }
         startNode=startNode.next;
         counter++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

In this we check for the fromIndex and toIndex being valid if not then it throws an exception.
We loop through the entire list & put in the elements which are only between the indexes supplied.

---

As per the comment

Yes your Add is also incorrect.
What you want to do is set the head node first.

```
public void add(Node<L> node) {
    if(head==null){
       head=node;
    } else {
      getFinal().next = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have looked at your suggestion and ended up writing my own add method. I'm not sure why it still doesn't work...though I suppose firstly could you tell me why my add method is wrong (what I assume is the cause)?

Comment: @MobBarley Please check the edit. Your head was also not correct

Comment: @MobBarley "ended up writing my own add method" sounds rather like you were provided with an add method as part of an assigned and need to write your code against that.  If so, it may be a good idea not to modify it unless it is completely broken.

Comment: @wrongAnswer I have fixed the add method. This is just practice so I wasn't given any written methods beforehand. I have tried out what you gave me for the while loop, adjusting a few things to fit what I'm getting at (toIndex and fromIndex are inclusive so I've added equals rather than just less or greater than), but now I'm entering an infinite loop with the equals. I don't understand why this happens though as the code does look "fine"...

Comment: @MobBarley without looking at your code its a shot in the dark. Have you change && to || ? if you share your code I could take a look at it. Please edit the question. Do not post the code as an comment.

Comment: @wrongAnswer Yes, I did edit my question, forgot to mention that. Updated code is at the bottom of it. I've tried changing && to || but I still enter an infinite loop

Comment: When you create the node and send it to add(Node) what is the next pointer of that node ? Seems you have loop in you linked list.

Comment: @wrongAnswer but then it should exit the loop when the node is null after looping through. Isn't that what the code (seems to be) is doing?

Comment: @MobBarley read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list) to make your doubts clear.

Comment: @wrongAnswer so you're saying that my last node is referring back to the head node? I thought I was using a singular linked list rather than a circular one

Comment: I cannot tell you for sure.It might be pointing to some node in the list may not be the head node.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already know it, but, have you tried `LinkedList.sublist()`? Here you have an example:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class GetSubListLinkedListJavaExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create LinkedList object
    LinkedList lList = new LinkedList();

    //add elements to LinkedList
    lList.add("1");
    lList.add("2");
    lList.add("3");
    lList.add("4");
    lList.add("5");

    System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + lList);

    /*
     * To get a sublist from Java LinkedList, use
     * List subList(int start, int end) method.
     *
     * This method returns portion of list containing element from start index
     * inclusive to end index exclusive.
     */

    List lst = lList.subList(1,4);
    System.out.println("Sublist contains : " + lst);

    /*
     * Please note that sublist is backed by the original list, so any changes
     * made to sublist will also be reflected back to original LinkedList
     */

     //remove element from sublist
     lst.remove(2);
     System.out.println("Sublist now contains : " + lst);
     System.out.println("Original LinkedList now contains : " + lList);
  }
}

/*
Output would be
LinkedList contains : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Sublist contains : [2, 3, 4]
Sublist now contains : [2, 3]
Original LinkedList now contains : [1, 2, 3, 5]
*/
```

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: This is not an answer the OP clearly said that they are writing there own implementation.

Comment: I can't see what you say. I clearly wrote "Maybe you already know it". Sometimes you are writing a method and you detect it already exists after having a look at the API.

Comment: While for actual use the Java API would be preferable, this looks like a homework assignment so I imagine Mob Barley would like a little more information on the how of linked lists, rather than which to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Using java 8 Stream function you can get sublist from any given type of List**

**if you want specific type of List, instead of List<> then you can cast the return type in the method into that specific type of List**

To get the sublist of any type of giving List like ArrayList, LinkedList, ArrayDeque
Below method can be used to get sub list of any type

```
package com.techsqually.datastructure.collections.lists.linkedlist;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LinkedListTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> giveString = new LinkedList<>();
        giveString.add(1);
        giveString.add(2);
        giveString.add(3);
        giveString.add(4);
        giveString.add(3);
        giveString.add(5);

        System.out.println(giveString);
        System.out.println(getSubList(giveString,0,3));
    }

    public static List getSubList(LinkedList<Integer> givenList, int startIndexInclusive, int endIndexExclusive){

        return givenList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(startIndexInclusive,endIndexExclusive);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]

[1, 2, 3]