# Writing subList method for LinkedList

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, sublist

As part of an assignment I am writing a singly-linked, non-circular LinkedList with a dummy head node, while implementing generics. The assignment requires implementation of the List interface, however I am stuck on the subList method. I have been scouring StackOverflow as well as the web in general trying to see an example of how it is done as I have tried several different methods of my own design, but the changes in the subList don't reflect to the original LinkedList. I rewrote my method to try and follow the structure of top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383377/linked-list-sublist-method-java) (to an extent, I don't want any helper methods), and here is my resulting code:

```
@Override
public List<E> subList(final int fromIndex, final int toIndex){//FIX ME
  if(fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > this.size()-1 || toIndex < 0 || toIndex > this.size()-1){
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds on call to subList with fromIndex of" 
     + fromIndex + " and toIndex of" + toIndex);
  }
  List<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
  Node<E> cur = this.head.next;
  int count = 0;
  while(cur!=null){
     if(count >= fromIndex && count < toIndex){
        list.add(cur.data);
     }
     cur = cur.next;
     count++;
  }

  return list;
}// end sublist
```

Here is a snippet of my tester file, as you can see I create a subList with the correct Nodes, however changes made in the subList don't reflect in the original LinkedList, and I am not sure how to proceed to fix that:

```
New LinkedList has been created 
List before testing: [one, two, three, four, five]
Testing subList function with fromIndex of 1, and toIndex of 4
Printing subList: [two, three, four]
Changing data of sublist to 'six, seven, eight'
Printing subList: [six, seven, eight]
Printing LinkedList after test: [one, two, three, four, five]
```

I'm not sure using a LinkedList as my subList is the correct choice, and any advice or criticism would be appreciated greatly!

**Edit: answered my own question below, I was essentially creating new Nodes rather than pointing directly at the Nodes in the original LinkedList**

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, in the hopes this is useful for anyone trying to look this up in the future.

So in my code I was using the add(int index, E data) function in LinkedList, which the way I had written it created a new Node and inserted it into the list, rather than merely changing the data variable itself. So I rewrote it so it no longer created new Nodes, and then I changed my above subList class to this:

```
public List<E> subList(final int fromIndex, final int toIndex){//FIX ME
  if(fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > this.size()-1 || toIndex < 0 || toIndex > this.size()-1){
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds on call to subList with fromIndex of" + fromIndex + " and toIndex of" + toIndex);
  }
  LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
  Node<E> cur = this.head.next;
  Node<E> pointer = list.head;
  int count = 0;
  while(cur!=null){
     if(count >= fromIndex && count < toIndex){
        pointer.next = cur;
        list.size++;
        pointer = pointer.next;
     }
     cur = cur.next;
     count++;
  }
  return list;
```

Now rather than using the add function I directly assigned the Node in my original LinkedList to the Node in my subList, and incremented size manually.

Unfortunately because each Node had a next reference, even though I manually added them correctly, when my toString function was called, it would iterate all the way through the LinkedList, including Nodes past my 'toIndex' until it the next Node was null. In order to fix this, I added an additional condition in my toString that included the size, and also changed my if statement for adding commas to the returned String:

```
public String toString(){
  String ret = "[";
  Node cur= this.head.next;
  int index = 0;
  while(cur != null && index < size){// added the index < size condition
     ret = ret + cur.data;
     if(index < this.size -1){// changed from cur.next != null
        ret = ret + ", ";
     }
     cur = cur.next;
     index++;
  }

  ret = ret + "]";
  return ret; 

}// end toString
```

So finally, my testing output looks like this:

```
Testing subList function with fromIndex of 1, and toIndex of 4
Printing subList: [two, three, four]
Changing data of sublist to 'six, seven, eight'
Printing subList: [six, seven, eight]
Printing LinkedList after test: [one, six, seven, eight, five]
```

While I am still learning and my code is likely not ideal, hopefully this response can help others with this same problem in the future!